# Detect touch nearby to CLLocationCoordinate2D in pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have few `GMSMarker` on `GMSMapView`, all of them are draggable, so when I longpress them, I can move them around the map. However I have also an action on longpress on GMSMapView, which adds a marker.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    self.moving = YES;
}
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    self.moving = NO;
}
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    if (self.moving) {
        return;
    }
    [self addMarkerAtCoordinate:coordinate];
}
```

Now the problem is, that sometimes user mistap and instead of moving marker he adds a new one. Because of this, I'd like to add small area around marker, where user can't add new markers. I've thought about something like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CGFloat zoomFactor = 35.f - self.mapView.camera.zoom;
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
    for (GMSMarker *marker in self.markers) {
        CLLocation *sectorLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:marker.position.latitude longitude:marker.position.longitude];
        if ([location distanceFromLocation:sectorLocation] < zoomFactor) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But of course I don't like this solution, because the area is changing with changed zoom. I'd like something like a finger width around marker to be longpress banned. How to calculate this distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to convert coordinate to location on view using method `pointForCoordinate:` on `GMSProjection` `GMSMapView` object.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CGPoint longpressPoint = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:coordinate];
    for (GMSMarker *marker in self.markers) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D markerCoordinate = marker.position;
        CGPoint sectorPoint = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:markerCoordinate];
        if (fabsf(longpressPoint.x - markerCoordinate.x) < 30.f && fabsf(longpressPoint.y - markerCoordinate.y) < 30.f) { // 30.f ofc should be defined as constant
            // handle situation when touchpoint is too close to marker
        }
    }
}
```